# using gcloud compute ssh - receiving "authenticity of host... can't be established" warning

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am having a hard time setting up ssh-keys on GCP. For some reason the target VM where I am deploying the ssh keys to, GCP can not establish the authenticity of the host, which in turn does not allow me to ssh via ssh-keys into the VM. (I redacted some information for obvious reasons)

I set up two VMs on GCP:

- artist-wrk-linux
- cuebot

they are both using the same user account.

To setup the ssh-keys, I am using this gcloud command:

on artist-wrk-linux:

```
gcloud compute ssh cuebot --zone us-central1-a
```

which results in this output:

```
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.  
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.  
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.  
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.  
Generating public/private rsa key pair.  
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):   
Enter same passphrase again:  
Your identification has been saved in /home/mario/.ssh/google_compute_engine.  
Your public key has been saved in /home/mario/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub. 

Updating project ssh metadata...
Updated ...
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                 
Waiting for SSH key to propagate. Warning: Permanently added 'compute.1240479947027764538' 
(ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
```

I can see a newly created ~/.ssh/autorized_keys file in the cuebot (target) VM.

And, I am now ssh'd into the cuebot VM.

As a sanity check I quit the ssh session and do:

```
ssh -T mario@ip.address.of.cuebot
```

which results in this warning message:

```
The authenticity of host 'ip.address.of.cuebot' (ip.address.of.cuebot)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:cM....
ED25519 key fingerprint is MD5:94:56....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

When I say yes, I see this:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'ip.address.of.cuebot' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
**Permission denied (publickey).**
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: the warning should be like this: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address ' ######### ' to the list of known hosts.Permission denied (publickey).And I think you missed the RSA part ,could you please confirm?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to GCP and don't know too much about ssh, but here's what I got:

`gcloud compute ssh` is a wrapper for `ssh`. You can see what it does by using the `--dry-run` flag.

For example:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh myinstance1 --dry-run
/usr/bin/ssh -t -i /home/ana/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o CheckHostIP=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.3772111379863307723 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/ana/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts ana@1.2.3.4
```

So you are getting the errors because you didn't tell the `ssh` command to use the custom private key `google_compute_engine`, and other options.